# Access to git Jenkinsfile url repo from within Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need simple thing:

1. Download Jenkinsfile from some repository. This is done on Jenkins project configuration GUI.
2. After downloading Jenkinsfile and starting the job, I need to get access to url from which the Jenkinsfile "I am in" was downloaded.
3. Checkout master branch (on multiple parallel nodes) using the url descirbed in point 2.

I am stacked on point number 2. Is it possible to access the url for repository from which the Jenkinsfile was downloaded? I don't want to hardcode it in Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really interesting case!
I have assumption that you are using git for checkout Jenkinsfile. So here is code for you:

```
println Hudson.instance.getItem(env.JOB_NAME).definition.scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].url
```

Jenkins will complain about security so you must approve signatures in Manage Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval

Answer (score 0):

I am using `scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].url`, but I am not sure whether you need an actual `checkout scm` step for the object to be present. The Script Approval is also necessary.

I would like to post this as a comment to the accepted answer but my reputation is too low :(